# SharePoint list column formatting schema do not resolve

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have the following column formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase(@currentField),'07') != -1, 'ms-fontColor-redDark','')"
  }
}
```

The first line give the following error:
`$ref '/properties/attributes/class' in 'https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json' can not be resolved.(768)`.

Replacing the schema link to `https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json` throw the same error.

The list did work properly last week, and with no changes to formatting I get this error and I have no idea on how to troubleshoot this. Same result in both Edge and Chrome.

Comment: I tried using the v2 formatting json and it is working for me `{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase(@currentField),'07') != -1, 'ms-fontColor-redDark','')"
  }
}` . Can you try applying the formatting on any other column or try to change the formatting a little bit to see if the formatting is working or not.

Comment: All columns give the same error. Can this be a change from central IT?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your column formatting and it works successfully.

I recommend you do troubleshooting, please try to change the formatting and then apply it to the other columns, check if the error still exists.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Want to point me on my way?